# NextJs Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'removeChild') on using third party blog post library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to use https://dropinblog.com/ with nextjs, the page works fine and loads perfectly with no error the problem is when I click the navigation links to navigate to some other pages using Next Link it throws this error:
[image]

[image]

my page is /blog which the code is:

```
import Script from "next/script";

export default function Blog() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Script
        src="your-dropin-blog-source"
        strategy="lazyOnload"
      ></Script>
      <div id="dib-posts"></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you include the entire stack trace? Also, it looks like dropinblog is a paid thing, why not just reach out to their support?

Comment: Added the entire stack trace